# Automatically add a variable into context on per-application basis in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I want to add a context variable in Django, so that I could define its value on per-application basis, or leave it empty.

Example:

apps/someapp/views.py:

```
def_context_var('app_name', 'Calendar')
```

templates/base.html:

```
{% if app_name %}You are in {{ app_name }} app.{% endif %}
....
{% if app_name %}Subsections of {{ app_name }}: ...{% endif %}
```

I considered the following:

1. Declare a variable in the app (in a view, or in URLs), and make a context processor. But I can't understang how to extract that var given the request object.
2. Put decorators on views. Hm, I don't like the idea: too much boilerplate or duplicated code.
3. #1 but nicer: make methods (like in the example above) that are executed on server restart, write the data into a dict, then a context processor somehow (how?) gets the application name and extracts the data from the dict. Where do I put the method, the dict, how does the context processor know where the view object is in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `resolve(request.path)` in a context processor to resolve the current url. See the [django documentation on resolve for its return values](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#resolve), especially `app_name`.

Comment: Wow. I thought it returns just a tuple of function, args & kwargs. Blind spots... Thanks!

Comment: Ah, that's 1.3. Mmm... well, I had to use inspect.stack instead.